# validar checkbox angularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs

En relación a una pregunta que hice ayer [Validar si hay un checkbox seleccionado AngularJS](http://Validar%20si%20hay%20un%20checkbox%20seleccionado%20AngularJS)

Como ponía ayer, tengo una lista de checkbox y tenía que ver si por lo menos uno estaba seleccionado, pero me ha surgido otro problema, ya que con la función esa, valida todos los checkbox del formulario y claro ahora que terminé el formulario, he tenido que agregar 2 checkbox más una para la politica de privacidad y otro para si es mayor de edad, los cuales deben tener una validación aparte, una para el checkbox de la edad y otro para la privacidad

```
    <form id="formDetails" name="formDetails" ng-submit="sendForm()">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="topic" name="topic">Children's</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic"> Health & Beauty</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">Science & Nature</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">Crafts & Hobbies</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">History</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">Sports & Fitness</label>
            </div>
            <span class="error" ng-show="formDetails.topic.$error.required">Please select at least one topic</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 policy">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 form-info check-policy">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="age" id="age" name="age">I can confirm I am over 16 years of age
                  <span class="error" ng-show="error">Please confirm you are over 16</span>
              </label>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 form-info">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="terms" id="terms" name="terms">I agree to the terms of the Privacy Policy
                  <span class="error" ng-show="error">Please agree to the terms of the Privacy Policy</span>
              </label>
           </div>
       </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

He intentado modificar la función que me pasaron modificando el `input[type=checkbox]:checked"` por `input[id=age]:checked"` o el correspondiente id de los checkbox pero no me funciona correctamente ya que solo puede estar marcado el checkbox de la politica de privacidad que ya valida todos los checkbox pero si solo falta ese por marcar aparece el mensaje de error en todos los checkbox.

JS

```
var app = angular.module('formApp', []);
    app.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.error = false; 

    $scope.sendForm = function()
    {
        if($("#formDetails input[id=topic]:checked").length > 0) {
            $scope.error = false; 
        }
        else{
            $scope.error = true; 
        }

        if($("#formDetails input[id=age]:checked").length > 0) {
            $scope.error = false; 
        }
        else{
            $scope.error = true; 
        }

        if($("#formDetails input[id=terms]:checked").length > 0) {
            $scope.error = false; 
        }
        else{
            $scope.error = true; 
        }
    }
});
```

Como podría hacerlo para que cuando dé al botón valide los checkbox, de la lista `id=topic` por un lado, el checkbox de la edad por otro `id=age` y el de la politica de privacidad por otro `id=terms`

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo se puede simplificar solo buscando cada checkbox y verificando si estan checked. En el caso de los checkbox topic solo habria que buscarlos todo los que tengan el name="topic" y por lo menos 1 este checked. En el caso de age y terms, solo habria que verificar si estan checked con el metodo [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) de jquery:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.form = {
      ageError: false,
      policyError: false,
      topicError: false,
      isValid:function(){
        return this.ageError && this.topicError && this.policyError;
      }
    };

    $scope.sendForm = function()
    {
      $scope.form.topicError = $("input[name=topic]:checked").length == 0;
      $scope.form.ageError = !$("#age").is(":checked");
      $scope.form.policyError = !$("#terms").is(":checked");
      
      return $scope.form.isValid();
    }
});
```

```css
.error{
font-style:italic;
font-size:13px;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" id="formDetails" name="formDetails" ng-submit="sendForm()">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="topic" name="topic">Children's</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic"> Health & Beauty</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">Science & Nature</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">Crafts & Hobbies</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">History</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic" id="topic">Sports & Fitness</label>
            </div>
            <span class="error" ng-show="form.topicError">Please select at least one topic</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 policy">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 form-info check-policy">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="age" name="age">I can confirm I am over 16 years of age
                  <span class="error" ng-show="form.ageError">Please confirm you are over 16</span>
              </label>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 form-info">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms">I agree to the terms of the Privacy Policy
                  <span class="error" ng-show="form.policyError">Please agree to the terms of the Privacy Policy</span>
              </label>
           </div>
       </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Todos los mensajes deberían estar ocultos y el botón activado y es cuando hago click en el botón aparezcan los mensajes de error si no están marcados los checkbox por lo menos 1 de la lista y los de la edad y la privacidad, por eso lo intenté hacer de esa manera que era la forma más aproximada pero me seguía fallando ya que si seleccionaba el de la privacidad, me validaba todos los checkbox aunque no estuvieran marcados, sin embargo si marcaba todos menos la privacidad, me saltaban todos los mensajes de error aunque estuvieran marcados los checkbox y no solo el de la privacidad

Comment: Dale una mirada a la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, así ya me está funcionando